Can police break down your door for an unpaid fine warrant for a misdemeanor disorderly house?
If a person had a warrant issued for not showing up in court or paying a fine for a misdemeanor charge of having a disorderly house, would the police be legally allowed to make a forced entry to arrest the homeowner?
Would the circumstances be different if upon arrival it is obvious that the disorder leading to the original charge has been cleaned up so that they are no longer in violation of the original charge?

Why would the second paragraph make a difference? They haven't dismissed the charge, you still need to show up in court.

@Barmar, I understand that it doesn't pay the fine or excuse the failure to appear, but it does demonstrate a good faith effort to correct the conditions that led to the original charge.  That might be worth something, no?  (i.e. might forced entry be justified under escalation of the original offense but not for an unpaid fine?)
Anyway it was mentioned in the original question so I included it in my edit.

Details depend on the jurisdiction, but legal systems tend to take measures when summoned defendants do not appear. These measures can be disproportionate to the original offense -- not showing up as summoned becomes the point.

@o.m., Yes, but surely there are laws governing when forced entry is permitted just as there are laws governing the use of deadly force.  This question is asking about them, so I'm not sure I understand your point...

@MichaelHall If that was in the original question, my comment was intended to the OP, not you.

@Barmar, very well, but I think it's valid as I explained.  And if it isn't, a good answer will explain why.  If it gets reopened...  did you vote to reopen?

Yes
Police are allowed to do anything they consider reasonably necessary to effect an arrest (with or without a warrant). That includes damaging property of the arrestee or a third-party.
Courts give wide latitude to this police power; the police are even allowed to make mistakes such as breaking down the door of the wrong house.
The fact that the offender has stopped offending is irrelevant. Murderers still get arrested even if they’ve stopped killing people. In any event, in the OPs case, the arrest is for the offence of not attending court, not for the disorderly house.

"Murderers still get arrested even if they’ve stopped killing people."  Sure, but murderers are a real and present threat to the arresting officer, they are a flight risk, they are likely to destroy evidence, murder is a felony vs misdemeanor, etc. ad nauseum.  A response proportional to the threat should be the expectation, and surely the law, or even the warrant itself would require a diminished response in the case of a person who cleaned up their messy yard but has a few administrative legal loose ends to tie up.

@MichaelHall "A response proportional to the threat should be the expectation, and surely the law, or even the warrant itself would require a diminished response in the case of a person who cleaned up their messy yard but has a few administrative legal loose ends to tie up." Categorically no. A warrant dispenses with the need to consider almost anything but the warrant itself. There are "high threat" no knock warrants. But an ordinary warrant still has a lot of heft irrespective of its justification. Certainly, the discontinuation of the offense is entirely and completely irrelevant.

The heavy hand of the police state I guess...
